# Can't update apk with FileTransfer and WebIntent plugin

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I made an app using ionic framework. For auto update function, I used FileTransfer plugin to download the apk and WebIntent to start the installation. But comes an error: "Parse error, There was a problem parsing the package".
The downloaded apk is surely fine and the path is /data/data/com.myapp.app/cache/. I can start installation in file explorer manually. Even I copied the good apk from my PC to phone, the error still the same.

Following code is for downloading and installation:

```
$scope.updateVersion = function(){
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 10*1024*1024, function(fileSystem){
    fileSystem.root.getFile($scope.appNameWithVersion, {
        create: true
      }, function(fileEntry) {

        var localPath = fileEntry.toURL();
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();        

        fileTransfer.onprogress = function(e){
          console.log(e);
        };


        fileTransfer.download(
          $scope.updateUrl,  // set before
          localPath, 
          function(entry) {
            alert('download ok');
            window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
                  action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
                  url: localPath,
                  type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
                },
                function(){},
                function(e){
                    alert('Error launching app update');
                }
            );                              

          }, 
          function (error) {
            alert("Error downloading APK: " + error.code);
          }, 
          true, {
            //options for NULL
          });

      }, function(evt){
          alert("Error downloading apk: " + evt.target.error.code);                                               
      });
  }, function(evt){
    alert("Error preparing to download apk: " + evt.target.error.code);
  });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use null for options, tell the file transfer plugin that file you want to download is android aplication package:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.mimeType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";

fileTransfer.download(
          $scope.updateUrl,  // set before
          localPath, 
          function(entry) {
            alert('download ok');
            window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
                  action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
                  url: localPath,
                  type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
                },
                function(){},
                function(e){
                    alert('Error launching app update');
                }
            );                              

          }, 
          function (error) {
            alert("Error downloading APK: " + error.code);
          }, 
          true,options);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But it dosn't work. The downloaded apk can be installed  manually from other file explorer. So I think it is not the problem of the apk file. And I tried using another application apk file, the same error.

Comment: hm. then maybe your problem is inside webintent.startActivity.. try this plugin https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Comment: Oh..My fault. Downloading a file, no need to create a file first. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

OH..It was my fault. When using FileTransfer to download. No need to create a file first. So the code below are no needed:

```
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 10*1024*1024, function(fileSystem){
    fileSystem.root.getFile($scope.appNameWithVersion, {
        create: true
      }, function(fileEntry) {
```